# Read a field value from node.twig.html in paragraph.twig.html Drupal 8

Tags: inheritance, twig, field, drupal-8

I am trying to read the value of `{{ content.field_paragraph_text_color }}` from my paragraph template. But the paragraph is a child of node template, where the color field is available, how could I do this?

I have tried something like:
`{{ content.node[0]['#node'].field_paragraph_text_color[0].value }}`
and also to extend the node template into the paragraph one to then read this value inside a block. None of them seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

It should be either:

```
{{ node.field_paragraph_text_color.value }}
```

Or:

```
{{ content.field_paragraph_text_color[0] }}
```